# how to make getter and setter in angular of input field model property?

Tags: javascript, angular

could you please tell me how to make getter and setter of input field property .
I tried like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
      private _keyValue: string;
      get KeyValue(): string{
        return this._keyValue;
    }

    set KeyValue(value: string){
      console.log('====')
        this._keyValue = value;
    }

  name = 'Angular 6';
}
```

when I typed on input field my `console` is not printed why?
here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnvv6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This may be of some value to you: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Comment: You're not using the setter you created, you're directly binding to _keyValue

Comment: how I will use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the setter you created, you're directly binding to `_keyValue`

To bind to your setter, you must use

```
<input [(ngModel)]="KeyValue"/>
```

As `KeyValue` is the name of your setter